# ChaplinJS collection syncing issue

Tags: chaplinjs

so I have a collection which I fetch in application start like so

```
module.exports = class Application extends Chaplin.Application
  start: ->
  #   # You can fetch some data here and start app
  #   # (by calling `super`) after that.
    Chaplin.mediator.styleCollection.fetch().then super
```

After this home controller takes over and takes the user to the appropriate page like so

```
module.exports = class HomeController extends Controller
  beforeAction: ->
    super
    @reuse 'header', HeaderView, region: 'header'
    @reuse 'nav', NavView, region: 'nav'
    @reuse 'price', PriceView, region: 'price'
    @reuse 'frame', FrameView, region: 'frame'

  piece: ->
    @view = new PieceView
      region: 'main'
      nextPage: "style"
    @subscribeEvent "click:continue-btn", ()->
      @redirectTo {url:"style"}
      @publishEvent "update:progress", 25
    , @
```

Now when I get to the PieceView via my HomeController, I am expecting that Chaplin.mediator.styleCollection should have already synced, yet a few times during reload clearly the collection is not ready. So I put in some console.logs and here is what I see

console.log Chaplin.mediator.styleCollection outputs (all is well so far)

```
StyleCollection
_byId: Object
_events: Object
_previousSync: "syncing"
_syncState: "synced"
escape: function (value) {
length: 3
models: Array[3]
safe: function (value) {
__proto__: ctor
```

console.log Chaplin.mediator.styleCollection.toJSON() (this is where things break)

```
Array[0] <<<< the collection has nothing in it. I first thought the collection could still be syncing but that is not the case because the previous log showd _syncState: "synced"
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was a dumb fix.

in Application code I did the following

> Chaplin.mediator.styleCollection.fetch().then =>   super